# Sum values in a range based on the date from another column above the cells

Tags: google-sheets

Here are my data :

```
+-------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Date  | 01/01/2017 | 02/01/2017 | 03/01/2017 | 01/02/2017 | 02/02/2017 | 03/02/2017 |
+-------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Value |          1 |        0,5 |          0 |          2 |        0,5 |          1 |
+-------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I trying to write a formula that would calculate all values for each month. So with my example right here I would get 1,5 for January and 3,5 for February.

I tried something with `=SUMIF()`, `=OFFSET()` and `=MONTH()` so that it would only sum the values that share the same month based on the date above them, but I tried everything I always get a syntax error.

Does anybody have an idea ? Is it even possible without doing scripts ?

Thank you very much and have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I found a way with `=FILTER()` :

```
=SUM(FILTER(2:2;MONTH(1:1)=MONTH(XXX)))
```

Where `XXX` here is the month I want to calculate. In my case I do it from another sheet :

```
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   |                                A                                 |                                B                                 |                                C                                 |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | Jan. 2017                                                        | Feb. 2017                                                        | Mar. 2017                                                        |
| 2 | =SUM(FILTER('OtherSheet'!2:2;MONTH('OtherSheet'!1:1)=MONTH(A1))) | =SUM(FILTER('OtherSheet'!2:2;MONTH('OtherSheet'!1:1)=MONTH(B1))) | =SUM(FILTER('OtherSheet'!2:2;MONTH('OtherSheet'!1:1)=MONTH(C1))) |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Which gives me :

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Jan. 2017 | Feb. 2017 | Mar. 2017 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|       1,5 |       3,5 |         2 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```